# Jenkins - Windows XP Slave

Tags: ssh, jenkins, continuous-integration, windows-xp

I'm having big problems connecting a windows slave to a working jenkins CI setup.

1. How do you connect using command on the master? I've tried the following command:

bash -c 'ssh user@hostname cmd /c "java -jar C:/jenkins/slave.jar -text 2>C:/jenkins/slave_error.txt"'

This successfully connects, BUT all commands talk to whatever shell has been spawned by the ssh server. This should be a new cmd shell (is this akin to a new bash shell?) as if the local user ran cmd.exe. freeSSHd claims to do this, but I can't get it to work. Instead the sshd server shipped with cygwin spawns a cmd shell, which spawns an emulated bash shell, which spawns an emulated cmd shell, which calls "java -jar slave.jar".

It seems that through all those layers of emulation, a) some system environment variables are lost, and b) windows commands run slower. Does anyone else connect to windows with ssh, and if so, how? I haven't found any information on running windows builds remotely with purely command line calls.

The build works perfectly on windows 7 through Java Web Start.

1. Why does the Java Web Start option, which creates a service on the slave, disconnect after ~20 hours? This option works great, but we cannot tolerate this sort of unreliability. Windows 7 has no such issue.
2. Why is connection through DCOM seemingly impossible to set up?
3. In case anyone else is trying to use "Launch slave agents on Unix machines via SSH", it cannot work at all for a windows slave. Use "Launch slave via execution of command on the Master".

Any advice is appreciated.